# ReactiveMongo unrecoverable exception: not authorized on <databasename> to execute command

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

We are experiencing issues with the following DB error when using Reactivemongo 0.16.1 It started when we migrated from Compose to IBM cloud.

```
DatabaseException['not authorized on <database_name> to execute command { find: "<collection_name>", skip: 0, tailable: false, awaitData: false, oplogReplay: false, filter: { <some filter> }, readConcern: { level: "local" }, $readPreference: { mode: "primary" } }'
```

and unfortunatelly this is non recoverable, we have to restart all our services. It seems like authentication issue but we didn't any changes to our MongoDB when it occurrs. It seems like native DB exception so we could probably exclude invalid error translation.

If I try to simulate the issue with removing roles then Reactivemongo recovers from it when I put role back. Only on production does not recover from the issue.

Is there some connection string parameters or query options to avoid server restarts? May setting [readPreferrence](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/tutorial/connect-database.html) help?

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "non recoverable" (which code?) 2. Have first try to perform the very same `find` using MongoShell in the same context (from same place, same credentials)?

Comment: 1. By "non recoverable" I mean that reactivemongo is unable to recover from this error any other way than by restarting server in contrast to Java Mongo client which is not affected by this situation.
2. it affect all queries and it starts working again immediately after restart, Java client is not affected thererere it is not necessary to do it in MongoShell.

Comment: 1. There is absolutely no way a DB exception can take down the driver : show code/reproducer. 2. There is no way restarting the driver can change server side permission. 3. Current version for release 0.1x is 0.18.8

Comment: The problem dissapeared after migrating from IBM to Atlas